# Computing and adding a note in the middle of a figure in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to compute the middle of a geometric figure and create a node with some text on that coordinates. When trying to do some simple squares, I get

`! Package pgf Error: No shape named (0 is known.`

I'm using the following MWE on MikTeX 2.9.4248:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


%%% this draws a 6mm edged square provided the top-left coordinates are given
\newcommand*\squareNVSEN[3]{  
  \draw [draw=gray, very thin]
      ( #1 mm,  #2 mm)
   -| ( #1 mm + 6.00mm, #2 mm - 6.00mm)
   -| ( #1 mm,  #2 mm);

  \node at ( (#1 mm + 6.00mm)/2,  (#2 mm + 6.00mm)/2) {#3};
%%% I'm not sure how the formula is interpreted by pdfLaTeX
%%% for general coordinates: (x1+x2)/2 & (y1+y2)/2
%%% for coordinates and lengths: (2*x1+Length)/2 & (2*y1+height)/2
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tH]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    xscale=2,
    yscale=2,
    virtual/.style={thin,dashed}
    ]

    \squareNVSEN{0.0}{0.0}{A in the middle}
    \squareNVSEN{7.0}{7.0}{B in the middle}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{some text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `\node at ( {(#1 mm + 6.00mm)/2},  {(#2 mm + 6.00mm)/2mm}) {#3};` with brace`{` and `}`.

Comment: +1. And with `calc` library, it's easy to compute a node in the middle of two other ones: `\node at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {};`

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input. I'd tested the one with braces and it works for me. @vipa would you like to write the answer (so that it's not here in the comments section)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get what you want you should wrap the calculations of x and y with braces. But as suggested by SebGlav in the comment, the code can be simplified using the `calc` library. The default units used by Ti*k*Z is `cm`, i.e. if you write (1,1) this mean (1cm,1cm).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


%%% this draws a 6mm edged square provided the top-left coordinates are given
\newcommand*\squareNVSEN[3]{  
  \draw [draw=gray, very thin]
      ( #1 mm,  #2 mm)
   -| ( #1 mm + 6.00mm, #2 mm - 6.00mm)
   -| ( #1 mm,  #2 mm);

  \node at ( {(#1 mm + 6.00mm)/2},  {(#2 mm + 6.00mm)/2}) {#3};
%%% I'm not sure how the formula is interpreted by pdfLaTeX
%%% for general coordinates: (x1+x2)/2 & (y1+y2)/2
%%% for coordinates and lengths: (2*x1+Length)/2 & (2*y1+height)/2
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    xscale=2,
    yscale=2,
    virtual/.style={thin,dashed}
    ]

    \squareNVSEN{0.0}{0.0}{A in the middle}
    \squareNVSEN{7.0}{7.0}{B in the middle}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{some text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily complicating simple things. What you want is just a single
command like this:

```
\draw[draw=gray, very thin] (#1mm,#2mm) rectangle ++(-6mm,-6mm) node[pos=.5] {#3};
```

and you can call it wherever you want. The `rectangle` is a basic drawing object and it supports a `node` at the specified `pos`ition.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand*\squareNVSEN[3]{
  \draw[draw=gray, very thin] (#1mm,#2mm) rectangle ++(-6mm,-6mm) node[pos=.5] {#3}; 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    xscale=2,
    yscale=2,
    virtual/.style={thin,dashed}
    ]
    \squareNVSEN{0.0}{0.0}{A in the middle}
    \squareNVSEN{7.0}{7.0}{B in the middle}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{some text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @AboAmmar! Please don't get me wrong - I would prefer your solution, but if I'm not writing Tex code for the next 2-3 months I might forget what your code does and how to enhance it

Comment: All the respect. To me, though, it's the contrary; my code says what it does (draw a rectangle with a node at the center). If I come across the other code at some point in the future, I have to decipher what this sequence of drawing commands is supposed to do. Besides, standard shapes should be easy to remember in TikZ.